# Search bar subviews not working and UITextField delegate methods not called for searchbar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

Please see my below code :

I have a searchbar in my viewController

```
 for (UIView *subView in  self.searchBar.subviews) 
     {
      if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) 
       {      
        [(UITextField *)subView setDelegate:self];
        [(UITextField *)subView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
        [(UITextField *)subView setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping-Search"]];
      }
    }

for (UIView *subview in self.searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```

This code is working fine in iOS 6 but not working in iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

The searchBar sub views hierarchy has been changed in iOS7, try the below:

**iOS7:**

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
```

**iOS6 and before:**

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews =  self.searchBar.subviews;
```

**Try below updated function:**

```
for (UIView *subView in searchBarSubViews) {
      if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) 
       {      
        [(UITextField *)subView setDelegate:self];
        [(UITextField *)subView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
        [(UITextField *)subView setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping-Search"]];
      }
}

for (UIView *subview in searchBarSubViews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}
```